# Search view onQueryTextChange issue

Tags: android, searchview

I implemented a **search view**, that searches from recycler view & update recycler accordingly. When It doesn't matches any item I am showing another layout "No Record" and set recycler view visibility to **GONE**. Suppose recycler view contains an item with title **"judge"** and when I type first two letters **"ju"**, it updates recycler view with judge on top.

**Now the problem is:**

1. When I type **"juz"** it should show *NoRecord* but it is showing blank white screen.
2. When I type **"juzm"** it show *NoRecord* and hide recycler view that is working good but when I backspace search text to **"juz"** it show *NoRecord*, again backspace **"ju"** it show *NoRecord* and again backspace **"j"** it shows that *item*.

**Search View method**

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
    newsListAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
    if (newsListAdapter.getItemCount() > 0) {
        listRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        noRecord.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        listRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        noRecord.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
    return false;
}
```

**Filter Method of adapter**

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
            String charString = charSequence.toString();
            if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                filteredNewsList = newsList;
            } else {
                List<News.ArticlesBean> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (News.ArticlesBean row : newsList) {
                    if (row.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase())) {
                        filteredList.add(row);
                    }
                }

                filteredNewsList = filteredList;
            }

            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = filteredNewsList;
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            filteredNewsList = (ArrayList<News.ArticlesBean>) filterResults.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: use `filter(query, listener)`

Comment: @pskink can you explain ?

Comment: did you read `android.widget.Filter` API documentation? if so, whats unclear?

Comment: Yup thanks, I read now. Can you guide me how to implement, my code is above

Comment: @pskink ok :)..

Comment: everyone has implemented `performFiltering method`. unable to find any help implementing `filter method`

Comment: err? i have no idea what you mean...

Comment: i don't know how to implement `filter(query, listener)`.

Comment: so what exact problems do you have? did you check when listener method is called? what does the documentation say?

Comment: how to pass listener in `filter` method, and I have to copy code from `performFiltering` to `filter` method?

Comment: how to pass listener? i already posted: `newsListAdapter.getFilter().filter(query, listener);`

Answer (score 1):

**This worked**

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
    Filter.FilterListener listener = new Filter.FilterListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFilterComplete(int count) {
            if (newsListAdapter.getItemCount() <=0) {
                listRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                noRecord.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                listRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                noRecord.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    };
    newsListAdapter.getFilter().filter(query, listener);
    return false;
}
```